# Issue consuming from fully qualified queue name on wildcard address

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have an address and a queue defined as following in `broker.xml`:

```xml
    <address-settings>
      ...
      <auto-create-queues>false</auto-create-queues>
      <auto-create-addresses>false</auto-create-addresses>
    </address-settings>
    <addresses>
      <address name="news.world.#">
        <multicast>
          <queue name="america.sport"/>
        </multicast>
      </address>
      ...
```

I have an AMQP consumer listening on `news.world.#`, and a sender sending messages to `news.world.#::america.sport`.

The messages are getting sent without an error, but they are not arriving at my consumer. I do see them getting queued in the `america.sport` queue in the broker's console though.
Am I misconfiguring the address/queue here or missing something in the concept?

Comment: Can you provide the code for your AMQP consumer? Do you see any other queues on the address `news.world.#` via the web console while the consumer is connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like maybe you've got some things mixed up conceptually.

The purpose of a wildcard address like `news.world.#` is so that any message sent to any address that matches the wildcard will not just be routed to the queues on the address where it was sent but that the message will also be routed to the queues on the wildcard address as well.

The issue here, as far as I can tell, is that you're sending a message using the fully qualified queue name (i.e. `news.world.#::america.sport`) which means the message will go to that specific queue and no other. However, your consumer is listening on `news.world.#` which isn't the same.

If you want your consumer to receive the message then you should *either*:

- Send the message to an address that matches `news.world.#` (e.g. `news.world.american.sport`).
- Create your consumer on the FQQN (i.e. `news.world.#::america.sport`).

Combining a wildcard address with an explicitly configured queue with FQQN is very strange. In over 10 years working with ActiveMQ Artemis I'm not sure I've ever seen that before. You may want to revisit your fundamental use-case and find a way to accomplish it in a different way.

Comment: thanks for the prompt response. let me ask you a more generic question then. is this possible to have a wildcard based functionality while having both `<auto-create-queues>` and  `<auto-create-addresses>` set to false? having a consumer for `news.world.#::america.sport` and sending there works, but it's not really functioning as "any sequence" matcher and won't cover a case of sending messages to `europe.sport` for example, even if i configure an additional queue.

Comment: i also tried to configure `<address name="news.world.#">` without any specific queues and send messages to `news.world.american.sport`, but again with no luck - getting errors that target address doesn't exist.

Comment: Technically speaking, wildcard routing is orthogonal to automatic address/queue creation so yes, it is possible for wildcard routing to work without auto-creation enabled. In general, combining a wildcard address with FQQN is probably not going to be very useful since conceptually the former is general and the latter is specific. They just don't really fit together very well.

Comment: If you disable auto-creation for addresses then you'll need to statically create any addresses you want to send messages to, even if they're just acting as placeholders to be routed to one or more queues on a wildcard address.

Comment: thanks again. i tried to config two addresses `<address name="news.world.#">` and `<address name="news.world.america.sport">` without any queues and sending a message to `<address name="news.world.america.sport">` indeed reaches both of them, but the interesting thing is that despite of having `<auto-create-queues>false</auto-create-queues>` i see temporary queues are still being created for each consumer on those addresses though.

Comment: What you're seeing is the expected behavior. The auto-creation functionality was added for use-cases where addresses and queues wouldn't be created during normal operation. For example, in the scenario where a client uses JMS to create a consumer on a topic the broker will create a multicast queue on the corresponding address regardless of how auto-create-queues is configured because it is required for normal operation. Not creating the queue would mean that no JMS client could create a consumer on the topic.